# What is the best way to open (embed) PDF file in microsoft visual studio 2010 express within Windows form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm doing simple program for searching of pdfs in DB and to open them within my software. For that purpose I'm asking what is the best way to embed (open) pdf within particular windows form? What I see in my microsoft visual studio 2010 express I don't have any component to showing pdf and it seems to use extra lib or component. So my question is what is the best solutions for opening PDF within Windows Form? I'm using VB .NET as language.

Comment: Do you have the path of your PDF file in your DataBase?

Comment: yes I have full path of PDF file in the file system